# Perform load testing and performance measurements of messaging queue system using java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, messaging, bigdata

Is there any Java program to perform load testing and performance measurements of various messaging queue systems like IBM WebSphere MQ, Active MQ, Rabbit MQ and Apache kafka

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I did a google search for "IBM MQ Performance testing tools" and the first non-ad link that came back was https://developer.ibm.com/open/2016/05/12/performance-testing-with-perfharness/.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka ships with performance testing tools such as bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh  and bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh